# I cann't send BTC on wallet Blockchain

Tags: error, mempool, bitcoin-wallet-app

When I try to send BTC i get error: BitcoindException(super=com.neemre.btcdcli4j.core.BitcoindException: Error #-26: 66: mempool min fee not met, code=-26).
My wallet is on blockchain.info, I set hight fee: priority, 1000,2000 and 3000 sat/b. And i get same probleb. Help me plz. Why can not I send btc??

Comment: If your wallet is on blockchain.info, why is this question tagged with [tag:bitcoin-wallet-app], which is an Android mobile app that has nothing to do with blockchain.info?

Comment: If you're really sending from blockchain.info, then this is something you have to take up with their customer support.

Comment: I wrote on the Sapport more than once. Saport is overloaded now. Do not unsubscribe. I thought maybe someone had this situation.